# Обращение к объекту через this и тег

Tags: jquery, javascript

есть какой то список но это не важно

```
<ul>
  <li><b>text1</b></li>
  <li><b>text2</b></li>
  <li><b>text3</b></li>
  <li><b>text4</b></li>
</ul>
```

его я обрабатываю таким кодом

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
alert($(this).html());
});
```

естественно, вылетает `<b>textN</b>` при клике. как сделать что бы вылетл только `textN` ???  я пытался

```
  $(this).$('b').html()
```

не получалось 
и так еще пробовал

```
$(this 'b').html()
```

тоже без ответа выдает ошибку

### [ссылка на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/igolka97/xxmCB/)

P.S. в место `'ul li'` не надо предлагать `'ul li b'` так как у меня каждое `li` является большой площадью и событие должно работать именно на нее

### [отформатированный вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/igolka97/xxmCB/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. попробуйте

   $(this).children('b').html();
2. попробуйте

   $(this).text();

Comment: оба варианта работают. спасибо

Comment: Естественно. Я написал попробуйте, чтобы вы выбрали оптимальный. 
Есть еще третий вариант:

$(this).children('b').text();

Отличие всех трех вариантов в том, что именно будет выведено.

    <ul>
    <li>Шла <b>саша</b> по <b><i>шоссе</i></b></li>
    </ul>

Первый выводит HTML из всех жирных надписей в данном элементе.

    саша <i>шоссе</i>

Второй выводит весь ТЕКСТ из элемента списка, даже если он не обрамлен тэгами.

    Шла саша по шоссе

Третий выводит только ТЕКСТ из жирных надписей элемента списка.

    саша шоссе